# Python subprocess.Popen doesn't take text argument

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.6

According to the Python 3 documentation for [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), the class constructor takes an optional argument `text` (which is supposed to control whether the file objects stdin, stdout and stderr are opened in text mode).

However, when I try setting `text=true` upon construction of a `Popen` object, I get the error

```
Failed: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'
```

and when I look in the source code (I'm using Python 3.6.4), the constructor takes no argument `text`. What is going on here? Why does the documentation say the constructor takes an optional argument `text` when it doesn't in the version of `subprocess.py` that I have?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have the feeling the text parameter has been added in 3.7, not 3.6.

Relevant part of the doc:

> Changed in version 3.7: Added the text parameter, as a more understandable alias of universal_newlines. Added the capture_output parameter.

Comment: Ah, that's probably it. A little strange that that comment has been added to `subprocess.run` but not to `subprocess.Popen`, though.

Comment: Ah! You forgot to accept my answer :) @HelloGoodbye

Comment: Indeed, using `universal_newlines=True` instead of `text=True` worked.

Answer (score 1):

As @Cecile said, some parameters like `text` and `capture_output` have been added in 3.7.

So in order to run some commands in it you can try the following code:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run('git --version', shell=True, check=True, universal_newlines=False)
```

If you want to capture the output (capture_output) in version 3.6 try the following:

```
from subprocess import PIPE
import subprocess

subprocess.run('git --version', shell=True, check=True, universal_newlines=False, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

**P.S.** For more information, you can checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209127/subprocess-unexpected-keyword-argument-capture-output/53209196#53209196).