# subprocess: unexpected keyword argument capture_output

Tags: python, subprocess

When executing `subprocess.run()` as given in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), I get a TypeError:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run(["ls", "-l", "/dev/null"], capture_output=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_output'
```

I am running Python 3.6.6:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.6
```

Comment: `capture_output` is new in Python 3.7.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

You inspected the wrong documentation, for [python-3.6](/questions/tagged/python-3.6) this parameter does *not* exist, as can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) (you select the version at the top left):

> ```
> subprocess.run(args, *, stdin=None, input=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
>                shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None, check=False, encoding=None,
>                errors=None, env=None)
> ```

You can however easily "emulate" this by setting both `stdout` and `stderr` to `PIPE`:

```
from subprocess import PIPE

subprocess.run(["ls", "-l", "/dev/null"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

In fact, if we look at the source code of the [python-3.7](/questions/tagged/python-3.7) version, where the feature was introduced, we see in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.8/Lib/subprocess.py#L481-L486):

> ```
> if capture_output:
>     if ('stdout' in kwargs) or ('stderr' in kwargs):
>         raise ValueError('stdout and stderr arguments may not be used '
>                          'with capture_output.')
>     kwargs['stdout'] = PIPE
>     kwargs['stderr'] = PIPE
> ```

Comment: I get "name 'PIPE' is not defined" if I try to use the solution provided here.

Comment: @ScottF: you did import it `from subprocess import PIPE` (as you can see at the top of the code fragment)?

Comment: you could also just use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to the same effect without the import

Answer (score 9):

The simplest method is to use the [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-l", "/dev/null"])
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error because I was calling [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) (which is the old high level API) instead of [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).