# Run sed for subset of arguments at time

Tags: python, sed

I am currently running sed in a python subprocess, however I am receiving the error:

```
"OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long: 'sed'"
```

The Python code is:

```
subprocess.run(['sed', '-i',
                '-e', 's/#/pau/g',
                *glob.glob('label_POS/label_phone_align/dump/*')], check=True)
```

Where the /dump/ directory has ~13,000 files in it. I have been told that I need to run the command for subsets of the argument list, but I'm can't find how to do that.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, you can just run `xargs` to invoke `sed` for you. Provide the filenames to the subprocess' stdin pipe instead of as command-line arguments.

Comment: Alternatively, ditch `sed` and use pure Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31499114/2790838

Answer (score 1):

Whoever told you that probably meant that you need to split up the glob and run multiple separate commands:

```
files = glob.glob('label_POS/label_phone_align/dump/*')
i = 0
scale = 100
# process in units of 100 filenames until we have them all
while scale*i < len(files):
    subprocess.run(['sed', '-i',
            '-e', 's/#/pau/g',
            *files[scale*i:scale*(i+1)]], check=True)
    i += 1
```

and then amalgamate all that output however you need, after the fact. I don't know how many inputs the `sed` command can accept from the command line, but it's apparently less than 13,000. You can keep changing `scale` until it doesn't error.

Answer (score 0):

Please scroll down to the end of this answer for the solution I recommend for your specific problem. There's a bit of background here for context and/or future visitors grappling with other "argument list too long" errors.

The `exec()` system call has a size limit; you cannot pass more than `ARG_MAX` bytes as arguments to a process, where this system constant's value can usually be queried with the `getconf ARG_MAX` command on modern systems.

```py
import glob
import subprocess

arg_max = subprocess.run(['getconf', 'ARG_MAX'],
    text=True, check=True, capture_output=True
    ).stdout.strip()
arg_max = int(arg_max)

cmd = ['sed', '-i', '-e', 's/#/pau/g']
files = glob.glob('label_POS/label_phone_align/dump/*')
while files:
    base = sum(len(x) for x in cmd) + len(cmd)
    for l in range(len(files)):
        base += 1 + len(files[l])
        if base > arg_max:
            l -= 1
            break
    subprocess.run(cmd + files[0:l+1], check=True)
    files = files[l+1:]
```

Of course, the `xargs` command already does exactly this for you.

```py
import subprocess
import glob

subprocess.run(
    ['xargs', '-r', '-0', 'sed', '-i', '-e', 's/#/pau/g'],
    input=b'\0'.join([x.encode() for x in glob.glob('label_POS/label_phone_align/dump/*') + ['']]),
    check=True)
```

Simply removing the long path might be enough in you case, though. You are repeating `label_POS/label_phone_align/dump/` in front of every file name in the argument array.

```py
import glob
import subprocess
import os

path = 'label_POS/label_phone_align/dump'
files = [os.path.basename(file)
    for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*'))]
subprocess.run(
    ['sed', '-i', '-e', 's/#/pau/g', *files],
    cwd=path, check=True)
```

Eventually, perhaps prefer a pure Python solution.

```py
import glob
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(glob.glob('label_POS/label_phone_align/dump/*'), inplace=True):
    print(line.replace('#', 'pau'))
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay, but the code takes hours to run and I can't feasibly try it more than twice a day. Your first suggestion using argmax returned a ````TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'```` and so I changed ````text=True```` to ````universal_newlines=True```` as per a comment on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52663518/11035198 and am running it now. If you have any other suggestions let me know

Comment: Also the path was not the issue as I attempted to run the code which removed the long path and received the same error.

Comment: `text=True` was introduced in Python 3.7; like you discovered, `universal_newlines=True` should work with older versions of Python (but is somewhat misleadingly named, as well as cumbersome to type). You can simulate a run by replacing the value of `arg_max` with a small number like 200. But the final code is probably what you should switch to; it completely removes the subprocess and so works around the problem entirely (and should be more efficient to boot).

Comment: "The path was not the issue" isn't really correct. If you are lucky, removing the 13,000 copies of the path will reduce the argument array's size enough to avoid the `ARG_MAX` error, but obviously that also depends on how long the names of the individual files are. On my Mac `ARG_MAX` is 262,144 so with that, we could accommodate 13,000 files whose average file name length is 20 characters in a single `sed` invocation. On Linux I think you should find that the limit is significantly higher. Conversely, repeating `label_POS/label_phone_align/dump/` for every file already consumes 429,000 bytes.